# How to convert Bytes received per second and Bytes sent per second to MB?

Tags: c++, wmi

I’m using **WMI with C++** to get the data usage of my PC (BytesReceivedPerSec en  BytesSentPerSec).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer

Those data are similar to the data from the right picture (Tab title = “Ethernet 2 Status” )  But I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert those data of the right picture (Tab title = Ethernet 2 Status ) to the left picture

[image]

(Tab title = Data usage). This formula doesn’t work **(Bytes sent + Bytes received)/1024^2** .  Even when I reset both data at the same time I don’t get the same result. For example (959.644 + 22.298.664)/1024^2 =22.180.850 I guess that’s 22MB thus not 11MB like the left picture tell me. I just don’t know how to convert those data to MB. Any help or tips would be really appreciated

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJune.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1B1p.png

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for converting bytes to megabytes is correct. Data in Data Usage menu is not realtime. What you see is a cached state. I cannot find information about how often it's updated.

Comment: It's updated every second. So every second the bytes (sent & received) of the right picture get automatically updated. For the left picture I have to do it manually.